# want my data in json format for post request

Tags: json, mongodb

I have data in this state

```
{prodName:"parle",prodDesc:"The fresh milk biscuits for children",prodPrice:"30",prodManufacturer:"biscuits"}
```

I want data in this form while doing post request and i am trying to get this value from

```
{"prodName":"parle","prodDesc":"The fresh milk biscuits for children","prodPrice":30,"prodManufacturer":"biscuits"}
```

please anybody can help not able to push data in mongo db

Comment: they are both JSON format. Looks like you need to loop through the keys of the first object and update the keys to include quotes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `JSON.stringify` to enclose keys with double quotes

```
db.state.find({},{_id:0})
    .forEach(function(d){
         print(JSON.stringify(d));
    }
)
```

output

```
> db.state.find({},{_id:0}).forEach(function(d){ print ( JSON.stringify(d))})
{"prodName":"parle","prodDesc":"The fresh milk biscuits for children","prodPrice":"30","prodManufacturer":"biscuits"}
>
```